# TОР игроков в игре.

Tags: android

Как в моей игре выводить ТОР-игроков без использования своего сервера? Возможно есть какие-то сторонние сервисы ?

Приложение, к примеру, кол-во тапов на кнопку. Кто больше тапнул - тот и в ТОРе на первом месте.

У Apple есть такая штука как Game Center и с помощью нее можно, на сколько я знаю, можно в приложении вывести топ по игрокам этого приложения, при этом не использовать свой собственный сервер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все уже изобретено и приготовлено к употреблению - https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards

То есть, Android Play предоставляет все необходимое, Вашему приложению только нужно будет отправлять статистику и достижения.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Вы уже использовали этот сервис ?

Comment: Нет. Я давно уже не пишу под андроид.

Comment: А, понятно) Спасибо за ответ!